# What is the proper way of initializing and finalizing the python interpreter in a C++ class in Pybind11?

Tags: c++, pybind11

I'm writing a C++ class which interacts with a Python module and exposes some of the functionalities to C++ clients. I believe the way I'm initializing and finalizing the interpreter in pybind11 is wrong and I'm looking for the correct way of doing so.

This is what I have done:

```cpp
class MyCPPClass
{
public:

    MyCPPClass(arg1, arg2,...)
    {
        py::initialize_interpreter();
        // the rest of the code such as initializing different py::objects etc
        this->module = py::module::import("F.MyModule");
        this->cls = this->module.attr("MyPyClass");
        //...
        this->obj = this->cls(**kwargs);
        this->start_fn = this->obj.attr("start");
    }

    int Exposed_Func1(arg1, arg2, ...)
    {
        return this->start_fn(arg1,arg2, ...);
    }

    void Exposed_Func2(arg1, arg2, ...)
    {
       //...
    }

    ~MyCPPClass()
    {
        py::finalize_interpreter();
    }

private:
    py::object module;
    py::object cls;
    py::object obj;
    py::object start_fn; 

};
```

I'm looking for a way to make everything self-contained in the class itself. that is I don't want to be doing something like this in client code:

```cpp
py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
MyCPPClass obj;
// use obj!
```

As I want all of this to be transparent to the clients and they only deal with C++ standard types only. What are my options in this regard?

### Updates

I noticed if I add the `py::scoped_interpreter guard{};` as the first field in the class, the error is gone and no crash happens. everything is fine.

However, how should I address this comment?

> It is totally wrong to use py::scoped_interpreter as a field. The interpreter is a singleton.
>   Creating multiple copies of scoped_interpreter is not possible.

Comment: The problem here seems to be that `module` and other fields are to be destroyed after `finalize_interpreter` is invoked. So i guess you should make `scoped_interpreter` a first field.

Comment: @user7860670 Thanks a lot. I removed the ```py::initialize_interpreter();``` and ```py::finalize_interpreter();``` and added the the ```py::scoped_interpreter guard{};``` as the first field in the class. However, if  the object is created on the stack it will not compile. but if I create the object on the heap (new it), it will run but will get stuck at the end and the program wont terminate!

Comment: `MyCPPClass obj = MyCPPClass();` makes no sense, use `MyCPPClass obj{};` instead. Anyway, "gets stuck at the end" is a different question.

Comment: I initially did MyCPPClass obj(); but that didnt work! I thought that was right! thats when I changed it that way! its weird to me as well!

Comment: `MyCPPClass obj();` is a function declaration... In modern C++ `()` or `=` syntax for initialization should  not be used anymore.

Comment: How is it a function declaration? my C++ is rusty but I do remember we used to instantiate objects that way as well. check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/)

Comment: Aha, so thats why. Thanks a lot. really appreciate it. 
but still the issue persists !

Comment: It is a function declaration because of [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The content on the site you've linked is total garbage... For instance multideclarations such as `int a, b;` are absolutely unacceptable, while in constructor initialization should be preferred to an assignments such as  `a = 10;`.

Comment: @user7860670 Thanks a gazillion times. you are right. I actually remembered the actual syntax, it was ```MyCPPClass obj;```. anyway, doing this, and following your suggestion the error is gone and no crash happens. but if I new my Class, it just hangs at the end. still no crash happens though!

Comment: It is totally wrong to use py::scoped_interpreter as a field. The interpreter is a singleton. Creating multiple copies of scoped_interpreter is not possible.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. then what should I be doing ?

Comment: First of all, you don't know what your clients are doing. Perhaps they want to use a python interpreter themselves, unrelated to what you do. You want to give them an opportunity to create an interpreter themselves. Then you may want to probably create a sub-interpreter just for your class. Pybind doesn't have sub-interpreter API bindings so you need to use CPython API directly.

Comment: At the very least, you want to create a separate, properly reference-counted singleton class which calls py::initialize_interpreter() and py::finalize_interpreter() in its constructor and destructor respectively. Then you reference (increment refcount) a singleton instance in your constructor and release it in your destructor (and optionally create/destroy a sub-interpreter there). So your clients may reference the same singleton for their own Python needs without interfering with your usage.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. thanks a lot. really appreciate it. I'll look into it